# Algolia docSearch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algolia, docusaurus

I need to implement **Algolia DocSearch** into my **docusaurus** project. I have got the api key and api id from the algolia. But facing challenges on what to do next. Please guide me the steps that I should follow next.

I have completed the frontend structure of the search box but not sure how to add data. How can we implement the search functionality? Do we need to send our complete data to algolia or to add some indexing, I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

It is all detailed in the Docusaurus guide to Algolia

https://docusaurus.io/docs/search#using-algolia-docsearch

You need to add the `Algolia` field in your `themeConfig` section of your `docusaurus.config.js` file as per the guide